# How do I manipulate the hover thing on bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I've tried making the tabs in the nav bar appear different colours when hovered, but the default hover thing keeps getting in my way.

This is what I'm talking about:[image]

How do I manipulate this or delete it?

Comment: Can you post your styles?

Comment: you need to overide the css property, the easy way is to put your styles after bootstrap.css in your html, then write your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is Bootstrap tabs hover effect styles:

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

It means that in order to overwrite them you need to take above rules and redefine background color with your own, but keep selector weight as strong (or stronger) as Bootstrap rule.